# Indexing in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The below code is used in My workbook for Indexing. Problem is this code is overwriting the cells in A1 with "Back to Index". How can I modify this code so it does not overwrite the current value A1 cell in each sheet and a Hyperlink in A1 cell with current value retained is created back to the Index page? TIA

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim l As Long

l = 1

    With Me
        .Columns(1).ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1) = "INDEX"
        .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Index"
    End With


    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        If wSheet.Name <> Me.Name Then
            l = l + 1
                With wSheet
                    .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & wSheet.Index
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="", _
                    SubAddress:="Index", TextToDisplay:="Back to Index"
                End With

                Me.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Me.Cells(l, 1), Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="Start_" & wSheet.Index, TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
        End If
    Next wSheet

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward to me but perhaps I did not understand the problem.

```
    With wSheet
        .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & .Index
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:=vbNullstring, _
        SubAddress:="Index", TextToDisplay:=.Range("A1").Text
    End With
```